# React-Select dropdown not functioning correctly with value

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using [React-Select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) in my application to create a dropdown and update some text boxes. Here's the very simplified code, which should get the point and problem (which I cannot find?) across.

```
import Select from 'react-select';
// other imports - react, bootstrap, ...

class UpdateMe extends Component {

constructor(props) {
     this.state = {
          options: [ 
             {label: 'hello', value: 'greeting'},
             {label: 'goodbye', value: 'farewell'} ],
          selectedOpt: '',
          textOne: '', 
     // other stuff in here not relevant, I believe, to problem
     }
}

handleDropdown(event) {
     this.clearBoxes();
     this.setState({
          selectedOpt: event.value,
          textOne: event.label
     });
} 


// in my render method in all the div's and stuff
<Select isClearable={false} className="dropdown-me"
 value={this.state.selectedOpt}
 options={this.state.options}
 onChange={this.handleDropdown.bind(this)} />
```

So this is a simplified re-write of my code. Basically what's happening is that when I click the dropdown, it **does not**:

1. Highlight the option when the dropdown is displayed
2. Display the name of the option on click

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me debug this issue! Thanks

Comment: Hello, does your `handleDropDown` function called. If so does it update the state accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select), `handleDropdown` function directly takes `selectedOption` as parameter, you need to write function like this,

```
handleDropdown(selectedOption) {
     this.clearBoxes();
     this.setState({
          selectedOpt: selectedOption ,
          textOne: selectedOption.label
     });
}
```

**Note:** `react-select` needs selected value in `{label: 'hello', value: 'greeting'}` format. Only setting value as `selectedOption.value` won't work.

Comment: This works perfectly. For some reason, it didn't occur to me to pass the entire event in rather than just the value. Thanks!